# using fscanf or equivalent for scanning strings

Tags: c++, file, stream, scanf

i already have a "complex" program, so i want to use following code if possible:

```
const char* path = filename.c_str();
FILE * file = fopen(path, "r");
if( file == NULL ) {
   printf("Obj File was not found");
   return 0;
} else {
   std::ifstream input(path);
   std::string line;
   while( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
      string sub;
      iss >> sub;
      // here i read in a lot of lines which are in sub
   }
}
```

now i need to seperate a line like this:

```
f 2/3/1 3/4/1 4/6/1
```

and found fscanf which should work like

```
fscanf(file, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &g, &h, &i);
```

but "file" must be a file. how can i input a string (sub in this case) into fscanf or is there another easy solution to read this line as short as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You want the sscanf() function.

```
sscanf(sub, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &g, &h, &i);
```

Comment: this helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @phil_ If your question is answered, please mark it answered.  Thanks!